# Nodejs syntax error inside docker but not outside

Tags: node.js, docker

I have a super simple node.js file that runs perfectly fine outside of docker, but throws the following syntax error when I try to run it in a container:

`./app/index.js: line 1: syntax error: unexpected word (expecting ")")`

`index.js` is literally one line:

```js
console.log("HI");
```

My Docker file is:

```
FROM node:14-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/app/
COPY . ./
CMD yarn start
```

I'm running the same command inside and out, same version of node etc. I'm on Windows 10 using the WSL 2 backed docker desktop. Could any of that have something to do with it? I'm going nuts...

Comment: Looks like you are not interpreting your file with nodejs but with something else, possibly bash... Make sure your package.json actually has `node app/index.js` as start script and not just `app/index.js`

Comment: This was totally it...*facepalm*. I guess I have rarely only used node to run things from an npm script. Somehow thought `scripts: { start: "./server.js" }` would work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
FROM node:14-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/app/
COPY . .
CMD [ "yarn", "start" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine with me.

---

index.js

```
console.log("HI");
```

---

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/app/
COPY . ./
CMD yarn start
```

---

package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  }
}
```

---

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  node_v14_test:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

---

Then build and run docker container with docker compose.

```
docker-compose up --build
```

---

Result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to convert file from dos to Linux issue or might the case image is using wrong code?

But the simplest way to debug that issue is not with **Docker environment** is to generate file inside Dcokerfile

```
FROM node:14-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/app/
COPY package.json .
RUN echo "console.log(\"HI\")" >> index.js
CMD yarn start
```